# MongoDB on Kubernetes Service Accounts

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Ok, second try and I will try to simplify the question.

I have single MongoDB cluster running on Kubernetes (using helm) and I want to configure it in a way that each microservice (service+pod) connecting to their own mongodb database on their has their own credentials.

**One way is to create mongodb database/users /password per microservice.**

Alternatively, can I use Kubernetes ServiceAccount and RBAC to abstract that from the database, so the credentials are automatically passed from the overlaying microservice to the underlying database.

thanks,

Comment: There is no question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create service accounts in mongo on k8s (and this applies to other services like redis/rabbit, which I have running on k8s)

Yes, you can create Service Accounts by following the steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/service-accounts-admin/).

Setup Service Account Token by following the steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#service-account-tokens).

> Can I assign a service account rights (rw) on certain databases

Yes, create `rolebinding` and `clusterrolebinding` RBAC permissions for the Service Accounts by following the steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#service-account-permissions).

Use this command to edit/update a Service Account:

```
kubectl edit serviceaccount <service account name> -n=<namespace>
```